# How do I make Grails execute a controller method on startup?

Tags: grails, controller

I'm a java developer and got to work with a legacy Grails application. I have a controller class and a number of java classes. The controller has methods to start/stop tasks described in java classes. I'm using a `ScheduledExecutorService` for that.

The problem is that each time application is redeployed I have to call `http://application/controller/start` to make it initialize the scheduler. I want this `controller.start()` method to be called once when te app is launched. How can I achieve that or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to put this method in a service. You can call the service both from controller and from Bootstrap.groovy after application starts. You can also use standard @PostConstruct on service to start the process.

Your business methods should be located in services not in controllers.

If you really need to use controller, try this from Bootstrap.groovy:

```
new Controller().start()
```

I don't have env to test it but there shouldn't be a problem with it.

Comment: Yes, calling the Controller method like that in BootStrap.groovy will work.

Comment: Actually the business logic is in java classes, the controller is just to control them. The problem is that when I put logic in a service I get a strange grails-melody exception which doesn't occur when the same logic is in a java class. I couldn't locate the reason of this happening, and decided to stick with Java as I know nearly nothing of Grails or Groovy